# Error in NewRelic on publishing to kafka in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, newrelic

I am publishing to kafka using kafka-python and have newrelic integrated in my application. the publish method of kafka-python fails due to an error **Error 'MessageTransaction' object has no attribute 'destination_name'** in newrelic

```
File "/Users/mishika/supply-metrics/app/kafka_manager/base_consumer_v2.py", line 55, in produce
    self.producer.send(topic, value=event_data, key=key).get()
  File "/Users/mishika/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/messagebroker_kafkapython.py", line 68, in wrap_KafkaProducer_send
    return wrapped(
  File "/Users/mishika/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 581, in send
    value_bytes = self._serialize(
  File "/Users/mishika/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 714, in _serialize
    return f(data)
  File "/Users/mishika/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/messagebroker_kafkapython.py", line 203, in _wrap_serializer
    topic = transaction.destination_name
AttributeError: 'MessageTransaction' object has no attribute 'destination_name'
```

my newrelic is initialised like this in main.py

```
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize()
```

```
[newrelic]
license_key = 
app_name = 
monitor_mode = true
log_level = debug
high_security = false
transaction_tracer.enabled = true
transaction_tracer.transaction_threshold = apdex_f
transaction_tracer.record_sql = obfuscated
transaction_tracer.stack_trace_threshold = 0.5
transaction_tracer.explain_enabled = true
transaction_tracer.explain_threshold = 0.5
transaction_tracer.function_trace =
error_collector.enabled = true
error_collector.ignore_errors = pycommon.exceptions.common_exceptions:DuplicateError rest_framework.exceptions:ValidationError rest_framework.exceptions:NotFound rest_framework.exceptions:ParseError
browser_monitoring.auto_instrument = true
thread_profiler.enabled = true
distributed_tracing.enabled = false
```

my metrics are being published to newrelic on logging operation along with transaction_tracer defined in my newrelic.ini file

I have removed the initialization part from main.py and removed metrics produce from logging operation and only kept what was defined in newrelic.ini file, But still facing the same issue

Comment: Following version of kafka, newrelic and python are currently used in my application

newrelic==9.4.0
kafka-python==2.0.2
python:3.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling kafka producer transaction on newrelic by keeping below in newrelic.ini file you would be able to send the message to kafka

```
[import-hook:kafka.producer.kafka]
enabled = false
```

I have also posted this issue with newrelic-python-agent [Error in NewRelic on publishing to kafka in Python](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-python-agent/issues/1045) for any further solve on enabling this kafka producer transaction on newrelic back